# GitKraken: What does "Keep New Version" actually mean during a rebase?

Tags: git, gitkraken

I haven't been able to find an answer to this in the GitKraken docs. During a rebase from my `branch` to `main` I'm getting a conflict that doesn't open up the conflict GUI and the message is vague.

[image]

When it says "Keep New Version" are the changes on my `branch` "New"? Are the changes on `main` "New"? Does this mean I'm adding something back into main that has already been deleted or moved? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can occur if one of the changes says "delete that file" and the other change says "update that file".

I wouldn't be able to tell you which side deleted the file, but if you wrote the code on `branch` you probably know whether you deleted that file or updated it.

Comment: So if I say keep or delete am I keeping or deleting my file on `branch` or on `main`? I'm assuming `branch`.

Comment: Yes : you are rebasing  `branch`, so after resolution, the commit will be part of `branch` (and on top of `main`)